# How to edit TextBox from another window

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I edit my TextBox (based in window1) from another window?

For example:

Window1.xaml

```
<Grid>

 <TextBox x:Name="LaboTextBox"/>

</Grid>
```

Window1.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Window2 win2 = new Window2();
        win2.Show();
    }
}
```

And now how to edit my textbox from window2?

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //what here?
    }
}
//or here?
```

Comment: What kind of editing do you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

**Example Solution**

**`MainWindow.xaml`**

```
<Window
Blahh......................
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
</Window>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="mainTxtBox" Height="55" Width="255" Text="{Binding NewString, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Button x:Name="newWindowLauncher" Height="55" Width="155" Grid.Row="1" Content="Launch Second Window" Click="newWindowLauncher_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

**`MainWindow.xaml.cs`**

```
public string NewString
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(NewStringProperty); }
    set { SetValue(NewStringProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty NewStringProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("NewString", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void newWindowLauncher_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    NewWindow newWindow = new NewWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this
    };
    newWindow.Show();
}
```

**`NewWindow.xaml`**

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="newTxtBox" Height="55" Width="255" Text="{Binding NewString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>        
</Grid>
```

**`Output`**

[image: Output]

**Example Solution 2**

**`MainWindow.xaml`**

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="mainTxtBox" Height="55" Width="255" />
    <Button x:Name="newWindowLauncher" Height="55" Width="155" Grid.Row="1" Content="Launch Second Window" Click="newWindowLauncher_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

**`MainWindow.xaml.cs`**

```
 string myString = NewWindow.myString;
 public MainWindow()
 {
     InitializeComponent();            
     mainTxtBox.Text = myString;
 }

 private void newWindowLauncher_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {

     NewWindow newWindow = new NewWindow();            
     newWindow.Show();
     this.Hide();
 }
```

**`NewWindow.xaml`**

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="newTxtBox" Height="55" Width="255" Text="text"/>
    <Button x:Name="StringUpdater" Height="55" Width="155" Grid.Row="1" Content="Update Text" Click="StringUpdater_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

**`NewWindow.xaml.cs`**

```
public static string myString;
    
public NewWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void StringUpdater_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myString = newTxtBox.Text;
    MainWindow win1 = new MainWindow();
    win1.Show();
}
```

**`Output`**

[image: Output2]

here is solution 2 you can update the string on window2 and update it on window1 textbox

Comment: That's not what I really wanted. Maybe I ask simple. In window2 I have my STRING that I what display in textbox based in window1. How can I make this?

Comment: @Kosky do you want this, On Window1 Load/Launch  OR  In case both the window opened and textbox on window1 update realtime without reloading window1

Further you Can Follow Example 2 i have updated

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a reference to your `TextBox` to your second window:

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
     private readonly textBox;
     public Window2(TextBox textBox)
     {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.textBox = textBox;
    }
}
```

You can access the `textBox` variable in `Window2` and access its properties, hence changing its displayed text, e.g. when a button is clicked:

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
     private readonly textBox;
     public Window2(TextBox textBox)
     {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.textBox = textBox;
    }

    private void Button1_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox.Text = "new text!";
    }
 
}
```

If you create the instance of `Window2`, pass the reference the following way:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Window2 win2 = new Window2(this.LaboTextBox);
        win2.Show();
    }
}
```